# How to rename react-native entry file (index.ios.js)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

When I init a react-native project, `index.ios.js` is created as project entry file.

Can I change this file's name and if so, how?

Answer (score 17):

When you start a react-native app you'll see this message output by the React Packager:

```
Running packager on port 8081
```

and then:

```
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/gbirman/gil/mapily 


React packager ready.
```

By this point, the packager has compiled your JS files and is serving them with the `.js` extension renamed to `.bundle`. For example, your `index.io.js` file is compiled and served from:

```
 http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle
```

If you added another file `foo.js` in the same directory as `index.ios.js`, the packager would serve it from:

```
 http://localhost:8081/foo.bundle
```

You can confirm this by opening that url in your browser.

Now to answer your question, your project has an `iOS/AppDelegate.m` file with [the following line](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/72d3d724a3a0c6bc46981efd0dad8f7f61121a47/Examples/SampleApp/iOS/AppDelegate.m#L29):

```
 jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
```

... as you can see, it loads the `index.ios.bundle`. You can change the path/filename there to whatever you want, but it's probably best to stick with the recommended approach of naming your entry file `index.io.js`

Comment: what about when using [offline bundle](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#using-offline-bundle)? **edit:** never mind, i figured it out... do that same thing but in `node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh`

Answer (score 12):

Suppose you've moved your `index.ios.js` into a folder called `dist`. You need to do two things

1. **For your development environment:** Update `jsBundleURLForBundleRoot` in `AppDelegate.m` to match your updated path.
2. **For your release bundle:** Open your Xcode project. You'll need to update the *Bundle React Native code and images* task under *Build Phases* for your project. Update the shell script in this section to look like below:

   `export NODE_BINARY=node
   ../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh dist/index.ios.js`

   `react-native-xcode.sh` accepts the `ENTRY_FILE` as an optional first argument, defaulting to `index.ios.js` if none is found.

   [Updated Build Phases Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G5eJ.png)

   [Reference - react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh)

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  This is needed after moving to TypeScript as the index.ios.js file gets moved to an artifacts directory.

Comment: Hi @abhishek, I’m using Typescript, and I changed my script to the following, but it still can’t find the entry file. Any idea?

export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh /artifacts/index.ios.js

Expected path `/artifacts/index.ios.js` to be relative to one of the project roots

Comment: I could be wrong but the leading slash might be causing your path not to resolve in Xcode. Try it without the leading slash `artifacts/index.ios.js`.

Comment: this one also helped me in combination of monoprepo setup and sentry integration, where my entry file was at `packages/mobile/index.js` https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/2701#issuecomment-1358707112