# Multiple RCTRootView in a single App

Tags: react-native

I am creating a react native app but i require the use of objective C to build my custom UIView. But issue is that this UIView need to display react content. e.g. a react text input and button. I am thinking about adding a RCTRootView (which will be having these react components) to the Custom UIView and thus solve the issue. But I am currently using one RCTRootView. How do i create another one and use it in my code.

edit:
I did understand that we can add different bundle with from server [how-to-rename-react-native-entry-file-index-ios-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694367/how-to-rename-react-native-entry-file-index-ios-js) but how to use that when i am running locally.

`jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create another RCTRootView, as you would any other UIView.

```
RCTRootView *someRootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:someJsCodeLocation 
                                                        moduleName:@"SomeRootComponent" 
                                                     launchOptions:nil];

RCTRootView *anotherRootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:anotherJsCodeLocation 
                                                           moduleName:@"AnotherRootComponent" 
                                                        launchOptions:nil];
```

You can specify the same bundle (`jsCodeLocation`) for all RCTRootViews, or different bundles for each RCTRootView. In either case its a best practice to have different component names (`moduleName`):

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SomeRootComponent', () => SomeRootComponent);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AnotherRootComponent', () => AnotherRootComponent);
```

If you would like to maintain multiple bundles you will need to compile each with the command:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8082/index1.ios.bundle?dev=false&minify=true' -o iOS/main1.jsbundle

curl 'http://localhost:8082/index2.ios.bundle?dev=false&minify=true' -o iOS/main2.jsbundle
```

main1.jsbundle and main2.jsbundle can then be added to your project and referenced normally.

Comment: Hi when i create bundles does index.io.js name important for the file. As i see that jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];

 Or can i name two js files like index1.io.js for 1st bundle, index2.io.js for second bundle and thesis it.

Comment: I did understand we can add different bundle with from server   [how-to-rename-react-native-entry-file-index-ios-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694367/how-to-rename-react-native-entry-file-index-ios-js) but how to use that when i am running locally.
`jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`

Comment: If i set the new root view in my view controller it will take that as the root or what happen? Can you explain me a bit clearly.

Comment: You can add them separately to the same view, or use them in different places in the app, or alternately set them to the root view of your view controller. They are each normal views, and the basics of UIKit here still applies.