# Creating new component fails: Unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native

I created a fresh react native project (version 0.47.1). Now I'm trying to write a new component for my react native app.

> /my-component.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Text>My Component</Text>
    }
}
```

> /index.android.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import MyComponent from './my-component';

export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyComponent />
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => Test);
```

The packager throws the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module `./my-component` from `<project_root_dir>/index.android.js`: 
could not resolve `<project_root_dir>/my-component' as a folder: it did not contain a package, nor an index file"
```

Adding the file extension to the import results in the same error, except with the file extension appended to the paths in the error.

The same error goes for dependencies added via npm. In any case the path shown in the error exists.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have moved the entry file i.e `index.android.js` into a custom directory i.e `test` => `(test/index.android.js)`. For this purpose it cannot locate the entry file. Placing the `index.android.js` again into the root directory will solve the problem.

If you want to change the entry point of the project you can refer the following: 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3442

[Change entry file path of android and ios in react-native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050253/change-entry-file-path-of-android-and-ios-in-react-native-project)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I displayed the file structure in a wrong way. The root folder is 'test'. Thanks anyway!