# Custom animated launch screen using lottie in react native project in xcode for ios only

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, splash-screen, launch-screen

I am using react native iOS app and I want to animate launch screen or splash screen using lottie. what should be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do animation on launch screen. The best approach for achieving this is by using this small trick:

1. Place an image on LaunchScreen
2. Create a view controller and place your animation in it.
3. Make this view controller as the entry point for your app.
4. Once the animation in your view controller finishes, navigate to your next view controller.

I am an iOS app developer and this is how most of us do it.

Comment: Thanks. I also thought about this and was wondering about a more proper approach. will you please tell me how to start react app from that viewcontroller as my app code is in react-native.

Comment: This is the only approach and the most proper approach ;) . And as i said, I am an iOS Developer and have no idea about react native. Maybe this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45048642/8374890

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into this package which contains multiple examples and best practises : 
https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is set the first frame of the lottie animation as your Splash Screen. Then create a custom react native screen as your first screen of your React Native app and place the lottie animation there. Set some delay and then navigate to your respected screen. For lottie animation, use this library:
https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native