# React native nagigation v2 setup issues

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to get a simple React Native app up and running with [Reative Native Navigation v2](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/tree/v2), and running into issues.

My steps are very simple and reproducible (I've tried them thrice now), so I must be missing something, but for the life of me I can't figure out what that is.

I followed the MacOS/iOS version of the [React Native - Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) "Building Projects with Native Code" instructions and got an app up and running as expected.  I then ran through the iOS section of the [Installing - React Native Navigation v2](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/Installing).  Then when I run:

```
$ react-native run-ios
```

(without changing any source files in the app) Metro Bundler starts up (like it did when the app was working) but now throws this nasty error

```
Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
(node:19701) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: File not found: index.ios.js in any of the project roots (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie)
    at getAbsolutePath (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/lib/getAbsolutePath.js:32:9)
    at Server._getOptionsFromUrl (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1056:31)
    at Server._prepareDeltaBundler (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:642:26)
    at /Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:761:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:11:1077)
    at /Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:11:1307
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:11:988
    at Server._processBundleRequest (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:839:32)
(node:19701) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:19701) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:19701) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: File not found: index.ios.js in any of the project roots (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie)
    at getAbsolutePath (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/lib/getAbsolutePath.js:32:9)
    at Server._getOptionsFromUrl (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1056:31)
    at Server._prepareDeltaBundler (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:642:26)
    at /Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:761:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:11:1077)
    at /Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:11:1307
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:11:988
    at Server._processBundleRequest (/Users/zposten/dev/moxie/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:839:32)
(node:19701) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
```

The first time I did this I used [Create React Native](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) and then "ejected" the app, which gave the same results.

The only piece along this route where I was questioning if I did something wrong was the piece in the [Installing - React Native Navigation v2](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/Installing) instructions where it talks about editing the `AppDelegate.m` file.  I literally took the block underneath "Its content should look like this" and copy-pasted it into the file.  I had one error the first time I did this, but I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44039891/2517147) and everything built successfully.

The error says `File not found: index.ios.js`, which is accurate.  I don't seem to have one of those, but the [React Native Navigation v2 Playground](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/tree/v2/playground) doesn't appear to either, and I have run this successfully.

I have the "app" published on the [`stack-overflow` branch on github](https://github.com/zposten/moxie/tree/stack-overflow), if that helps (it breaks in the final commit where I follow the [installing v2 instructions](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/Installing)).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Haven't tried ejecting but if you rename App.js to index.js, it should work. Otherwise you would need to update the entry file in your java/ios code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050253/change-entry-file-path-of-android-and-ios-in-react-native-project?rq=1

Comment: Hi @MattAft thank you for your quick response!  I do have [an `index.js`](https://github.com/zposten/moxie/blob/stack-overflow/index.js) at the root of the project, and it just calls to my `src/App.js`.  Shouldn't the root `index.js` be found as the app's entry point?

Comment: In the link i posted above, do those show up as index.js for you or index.ios.js/index.android.js?

Comment: The link you posted seems specific to android, if I'm not mistaken?  I don't have an android setup going yet.  But someone commented pointing to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30695976/2517147) which talks about iOS, and I found `jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];` in [my AppDelegate.m file](https://github.com/zposten/moxie/blob/stack-overflow/ios/moxie/AppDelegate.m).  But I don't really know what that means! Lol does that help at all? I do appreciate you're taking the time to help!

Comment: Yeah sorry someone posted the ios version a little further down. So it's set to index.ios which means that's its looking for index.ios.js which was what older versions of RN did. try changing that to just index.